# Suppress certain formats in Quill

Tags: quill

I have a Quill editor that needs to convert certain legacy content, which is already HTML, into the parchment delta format. Putting the HTML into the DOM before creating the Quill editor works perfectly:

```
<div id="my-editor">
  <p>My legacy content</p>
</div>
<script>
  var editor = new Quill("#my-editor");
</script>
```

However, some of the legacy HTML is very messy and contains certain style constructs (font, color, background) that I don't want to support.

Quill does a great job of ignoring tags, classes, and style attributes that it doesn't understand. But I'd like to un-register certain known formats that I want it to also ignore. I've tried doing this...

```
Quill.register({
  'formats/color': null,
  'formats/font': null,
  'formats/background': null
});
```

...in an attempt to un-register those formats from the Quill registry. But then I get this error at runtime:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'blotName' of null
    at Function.register (vendor/quill-1.3.2.js:1068:82)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, silly me... I found the answer myself...

I was looking for a way to ***blacklist*** specific formats, but the correct way to do this is to use the `formats` param in the `options` object to ***whitelist*** the formats I actually want to use...

```
var editor = new Quill(
  "#my-editor",
  {
    "formats" : [
      "bold",
      "italic",
    ]
  }
);
```

The configuration option is documented [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#formats) and the list of core formats available for whitelisting is [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/).